# Phantom MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException between two CallableStatementS

Tags: java, mysql, transactions, constraints, innodb

We got strange non-permanent error: MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException inside java transaction.
        Imagine next code:

**sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
        ruleID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(250),
        PRIMARY KEY (ruleID)
) engine=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE test2 (
        ruleID    INT(11) NOT NULL,
        name varchar(250),
        PRIMARY KEY (ruleID),
        CONSTRAINT _FK1 FOREIGN KEY (ruleID)
        REFERENCES test (ruleID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) engine=InnoDB;


CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(
        inout p_ruleID INT (11),
        p_name varchar(250)
)
    proc: begin
    IF (p_ruleID < 1) THEN
    INSERT INTO test (ruleID, name) values (null, p_name);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO p_ruleID;

    else
    UPDATE test
    SET name = p_name
    WHERE ruleID = p_ruleID;

    SELECT p_ruleID;

    END IF;
    END //


CREATE PROCEDURE proc2(
        p_ruleID INT (11),
        p_name varchar(250)
)
    BEGIN
    DELETE FROM test2
    WHERE ruleID = p_ruleID;

    INSERT INTO test2(ruleID, name)
    VALUES (p_ruleID, p_name);

    END //
```

**java:**

```
    Connection conn;
    int id;
    String name;
    String subName;
    ...

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    id=1;

    CallableStatement cs1 = conn.prepareCall("{call proc1(?,?)}");
    cs1.setInt(1, id);
    cs1.setString(2, name);
    cs1.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    cs1.execute();
    int parentID = cs1.getInt(1);
    cs1.close();

    cs1 = conn.prepareCall("{call proc2(?,?)}");
    cs1.setInt(1, parentID);
    cs1.setString(2, subName);
    cs1.execute();
    ...
```

So once during the "cs1.execute()" for "proc2" we got exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot add or update a child row:
>       a foreign key constraint fails (test2, CONSTRAINT '_FK1' FOREIGN KEY ('ruleID') REFERENCES 'test' ('ruleID') ON DELETE CASCADE)

We got it only once and can't repeat it. 
One "guru" said - java transaction, performed by Connection, don't garanty the visibility of results between CallableStatementS. 
Is it true? Or may be the truth is out there?